# Kendo UI datasource transport read ignore data parameters

Tags: java, kendo-grid

Hi everyone I'm becoming crazy with Kendo UI Grid component. I'm using  dataSource.transport.read to load JSON Jersey service in GET. The code is something like this:

```
 var args = new Object();
   args.procomfilter = "058091_054051";
   args.userGrid = "false";
   args.take = "20";
   args.skip = "0";
   args.row = "Comuni";

var _dataSourceGrid = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        pageSize: 20,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read:{
              type: "GET",
              url: "services/viewData/filtracomuni" ,
              data: JSON.stringify(args),  
              cache: false } } ....

var _grid = $(gridId).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: _dataSourceGrid,
        columnMenuInit: function(e) {
            var item = e.container.find(".k-columns-item");
            item.prev(".k-separator").remove();
            item.remove();
        },
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        toolbar: kendo.template($(gridId+"Template").html()),
        resizable: true,
        //sortable: true,
        columnMenu: !userGrid,
```

...

on firebug I see that args is totally ignored

but if I call directly :

```
$(_gridId).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
             read: { 
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "services/viewData/filtracomuni", 
                          data: JSON.stringify(args) 
                    }

        }
    }
});
```

it works, why?
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON.stringify(data)` is executed immediately when you instanciate the Datasource, and your data are not ready at this point. To solve this, you want to wrap your stringify in a function :

```
var _dataSourceGrid = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read:{
              type: "GET",
              url: "services/viewData/filtracomuni" ,
              data: function() { return JSON.stringify(args); },
              dataType : "json", 
              cache: false
            } }
```

....

Comment: thak you very much